# In Graphene, how do you provide both a list and a specific element from one?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

Right now, I have some code that lets me get all items, and their properties:

```py
import graphene

class Item(graphene.ObjectType):
    name = graphene.String()
    item_id = graphene.String()

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    items = graphene.List(Item)

    def resolve_items(self, info):
        return [
            Item(name="Enchanted Diamond", item_id="ENCHANTED_DIAMOND"),
            Item(name="Enchanted Diamond Block", item_id="ENCHANTED_DIAMOND_BLOCK"),
            Item(name="Power Crystal", item_id="POWER_CRYSTAL"),
            Item(name="Bejeweled Handle", item_id="BEJEWELED_HANDLE"),
        ]


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

However, I want to also be able to get a specific item. Right now, if I run the query

```
{
items(name: "Enchanted Diamond") {
name
}
}
```

I get a

```
GraphQLError("Unknown argument 'name' on field 'Query.items'.", locations=[SourceLocation(line=3, column=7)])
```

How would I provide a way to get a specific element, ideally without providing a whole separate endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify the parameters when I was declaring `items`. Here's the part of the code I changed:

```py
    items = graphene.List(Item, name=graphene.String(), item_id=graphene.String())

    def resolve_items(self, info, name=None, item_id=None):
        available_items = [
            Item(name="Enchanted Diamond", item_id="ENCHANTED_DIAMOND"),
            Item(name="Enchanted Diamond Block", item_id="ENCHANTED_DIAMOND_BLOCK"),
            Item(name="Power Crystal", item_id="POWER_CRYSTAL"),
            Item(name="Bejeweled Handle", item_id="BEJEWELED_HANDLE"),
        ]
        if name:
            return [item for item in available_items if item.name == name]
        if item_id:
            return [item for item in available_items if item.item_id == item_id]
        return available_items
```

I feel like this is better than declaring a whole separate `item`, even though I feel like there should be a better way to code this. (Investigating how I could use Unions to improve it right now)